# How to put condition after table join and ASC and Limit Record in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, database, hibernate, join

I have two SQL Tables: Table (A) and Table (B) . Table (A) match Multiple Records In Table (B). I successfully retrieve record list. And Sorting Using Table(B), 'revisionDate' column and take only latest record.

```
Select  TOP(1) *
from   A
inner JOIN B
    ON  A.id = B.[occasion]
where
    A.id ='136002' and
    A.[prescribedTime] >='2017-12-11 20:00:00.000'
ORDER BY versioningInformation_createdDateTime ASC
```

But I want to take this record only where Table "B" status column contain Data as '11' .

[image]

I try to used 'where Clause , eg: where adminState in (11) ,But I cannot success.

Comment: Please show your current output along with the output you expect.  Your question is not clear to me.

Comment: @Biegeleisen ,my current out put , return me one record.., but actually ,I want to return latest record , contain  'AdminState (11) ' .

Comment: @Biegeleseien , really I want to do, select latest record ,if there 'ADMINSTATE' only equal 11. this time' AdminStatus 'is 44. so, I expect, not return this record to program.  I don't know this is possible thing. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    SELECT * FROM 
(Select TOP(1) A.id,<rest of the cols>
from A inner JOIN B 
ON A.id = B.[occasion] 
where A.id ='136002'
 and A.[prescribedTime] >='2017-12-11 20:00:00.000' 
ORDER BY versioningInformation_createdDateTime ASC ) 
 tab

    WHERE adminState = 11
```

Comment: Thank you , but 'tab' word given error, 'The column 'id' was specified multiple times for 'tab'.'

Comment: In the inner query you need to specify the columns you want. Since id column is in both the tables so there is that error you see

Comment: Yes, when I chage sub querry   * to  adminStatus ,it work.

Answer (score 1):

```
ON A.id = B.[occasion] AND B.adminState = 11
```

Also, try changing it to an outer join, I think that's what you're looking for.  If not, you can add more details.

Comment: Ahad, Thanks for u answer.but in this case return me not latest record.This time me, return top record contain AdminStatus as 11. but I really want, after I select top record, IF it contain Admin Status as selecting that record. Are there any way, that kind of work. ?

Comment: try changing it to an outer join, Not exactly sure what you're looking for, but I think that's it

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on your comment to Abdul's answer.

```
SELECT *
  FROM (Select  TOP(1) *
          from   A
                 inner JOIN B ON  A.id = B.[occasion]
          where
             A.id ='136002' and
             A.[prescribedTime] >='2017-12-11 20:00:00.000'
        ORDER BY versioningInformation_createdDateTime ASC ) g
WHERE g.adminState = 11
```

Comment: Thank you.., I try this but given SQL syntax error. 'Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 94
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.' I used MSSQL Server 2014.

Comment: Sorry, just corrected it. Forgot to alias the subquery.

Comment: now, give like this error. 'The column 'id' was specified multiple times for 'g'.'

Comment: yeah, something like that will work if that's what he's looking for

Comment: @AbdulAhad this is i looking for. but still given error, 'The column 'id' was specified multiple times for 'g'.'

Comment: @AbdulAhad At this point I can't help you out any more. I don't know what your tables look like. But that's an easy enough error to correct that you don't need us here to do it.

Comment: @SamM sure  i will try.

Comment: yeah, it's probably that sub-table, not sure how that works

Comment: yes, when change sub qurry * to , 'AdminStatus' it work.